# java on linux - Have to press CtrlD twice

Tags: java, linux

```
String str = "";
BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int tempint = 0;
try {
    //The program cannot get out from this while loop!
    while((tempint = bfr.read()) != -1){
        str += Character.toString((char)tempint);
    }
}
catch(IOException ioe) {
    System.out.println(ioe);
}
//Print the input
System.out.println(str);
```

This is the code I wrote for reading user's input from standard input. This piece of code is extracted as `playinput.jar`
And I have written a script `play` to run this jar. But after I run `./play` in terminal(linux) and finish my input, which does not contain enter, I have to press `Ctrl+D` twice to get the input printed out.

The same problem occurred when I ran another script called `check`, which will simply invoke `./play` and send some input via `stdin`. After I ran `./check`, it just hanged there and the input cannot be printed out.

Could anyone help fix this problem? Thank you:)

Comment: I ran your code via "java -cp .../bin snippet.Snippet" and via "java -jar Snippet.jar" and via "./play". Both of them worked fine (just one ^D required). [using oracle java sdk 1.7.0_51, ubuntu 12.04.4, bash shell]

Comment: That's how Java works by design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just how the Linux terminal works. It has nothing to do with your Java code.

If you test it out with a command like `cat > textfile`, you will find that unless you are at the beginning of a line, `^D` doesn't immediately end the file as you might expect it to. (I don't know all the details of this behavior, but that's the gist of it.)

The convention for Linux is that a text file always ends with a newline. You can run into problems like this if you don't follow the convention.

However, I'm not sure about your problem with the program hanging when you send it data using redirection. That part is more surprising to me, since it's not interactive so the terminal behavior shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Thank you! At last I found the solution. The script run by ./check is written in Scheme and the input stream mechanism is different from Java. I solved this problem by using the available() method in Java's InputStream.